# Start with closed nodes in indented tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I used this indentend tree : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025

And i want to start like this :

[image]

And not like this :

[image]

The transition to change the node is this :

```
// Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .remove();
```

How can i do it ? Thank you again for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this at the end of the initial loading (after the call to `update(root)`) does the trick. It relies on the `_children` concept utilized here to store children not currently displayed.

```
root.each(function(d) {
    if (d.depth > 0) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    }
    update(d)
});
```